# Replacing a specific string from every key and value in a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, replace

So I have a dictionary that contains URLs and names. The URL addresses start a download and the names include the directory, name I want the file to be, and .pdf. My original list only contains a start date, of which I want to write a function such that I can change the date to download and name the next months.

```
def replace_date(dictionary):
    desired_date = str(input('Please enter the 3 letter date you need, capitalizing the first letter: '))
    for name, location in dictionary.items():
        name.replace('Feb', desired_date)
        location.replace('Feb', desired_date)
        print(dictionary)
```

When I run this function, the print statement of the dictionary still has the same month in both keys and values of my dictionary. I thought it might be that I needed to save them in the for loop like I did below but that didn't change anything.

```
name = name.replace('Feb', desired_date)
location = location.replace('Feb',desired_date)
```

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some example input/output?

Comment: Use `dictionary[desired_date] = dictionary.pop(name)` and `dictionary[desired_date] = desired_date`. It should help.